# Julia equivalent to python list multiplication

Tags: list, julia, concatenation, repeat

In python I can quickly concatenate and create lists with repeated elements using the + and * operators. For example:

```
my_list = [1] * 3 + ['a'] * 4  # == [1, 1, 1, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

Similarly in Julia, I can quickly concatenate and create strings with repeated elements using the * and ^ operators. For example:

```
my_string = "1"^3 * "a"^4  # == "111aaaa"
```

My question is whether or not there is a convenient equivalent for lists (arrays) in Julia. If not, then what is the simplest way to define arrays with repeated elements and concatenation?

Comment: check out `fill()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the above scenario, a shorter form is fill:

```
[fill(1,3); fill('a', 4)]
```

You could also define a Python style operator if you like:

```
⊕(a::AbstractVector{T}, n::Integer) where T = repeat(a, n)
⊕(a::T, n::Integer) where T = fill(a, n)
```

The symbol `⊕` can be entered in Julia by typing \oplus and pressing Tab.

Now you can do just as in Python:

```
julia> [1,2] ⊕ 2
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 1
 2

julia> 3 ⊕ 2
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 3
 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `repeat`, e.g.

```
[repeat([1], 3); repeat(['a'],4)]
```

produces `Any[1, 1, 1, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']`.